# Using “domination of” to show skillfulness

Tags: word-usage

Can “domination of” be used to show skillfulness
Examples:
1) Sarah has a great domination of mathematics.
2) He has a high domination of plying piano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domination of is usually used to give the meaning of power or influence over something or somebody. It's exactly not the skill itself, but a highly skilled person can have a domination of a subject. We would rather say, '***He has a brilliant command or English***' than '*He has a domination of English*)

### ODO:

> **1 the exercise of power or influence over someone or something, or the state of being so controlled:**
>
> *the imperial domination of India.*
>
> **2 (dominations) (in traditional Christian angelology) the fourth-highest order of the ninefold celestial hierarchy.**

### OLDO:

> **control or power over somebody/something, especially in an unpleasant way**
>
> *political domination*
>
> **domination of somebody/something**
>
> *companies fighting for domination of the software market*
>
> **domination over somebody/something**
>
> *the history of male domination over women*
>
> **the fact of being the most important or common feature of something**
>
> *the domination of photography in this year's exhibition*
>
> **(sport) the fact of playing much better than your opponent in a game**
>
> *The scoreline reflected Germany's complete domination of the game.*